# Vaadin 8 grid row height is not automatically adjusting

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I am working on the grid component in vaadin 8. In My grid, each column data fetched from the database and it may be too lengthy. the grid row height is not expanding based on the content in each column. My grid is given below.

[image]

You can see complete content is not visible in each columns.

Answer (score 1):

In Vaadin8 the Grid component rows are not auto-adjusting, i.e. this feature does not exists there. The Grid rows are of fixed height. There is an API to configure the row height e.g. `grid.setRowHeight(50)`.

This limitation no longer exists in the newer generation Vaadin frameworks, e.g. Vaadin 14.